Angular: <google-chart> Is it possible to have all vAxes of the left of the chart?
I have a line chart with multiple vAxes (y) and want all of them on the left. At the moment, only one is on the left and the rest is on the right.
Im using "ng2-google-charts" version 6.2.0 component and "GoogleChartInterface" on Angular 10.
My chart code in ts:
public indexesColumnChart2: GoogleChartInterface = {
    chartType: "LineChart",
    dataTable: [
      [
        this.translate.instant("Day"),
        `${this.filtersColorsData[5].label} km/h`,
        `${this.filtersColorsData[0].label} %`,
        `${this.filtersColorsData[1].label} C`,
      ],
      ["1", 5, 65.0, 12.3],
      ["2", 13.2, 72.5, 15.6],
      ["3", 15.9, 80.0, 18.9],
      ["4", 18.0, 87.5, 22.2],
      ["5", 7, 65.0, 12.3],
      ["6", 13.2, 72.5, 15.6],
      ["7", 1, 80.0, 18.9],
      ["8", 2, 87.5, 22.2],
      ["9", 6, 65.0, 12.3],
    ],
    options: {
      series: {
        0: { targetAxisIndex: 0, color: "black" },
        1: { targetAxisIndex: 1, color: "blue" },
        2: { targetAxisIndex: 2, color: "red" },
      },
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          title: `${this.filtersColorsData[5].label} km/h`,
          minValue: 0.0,
          maxValue: 18.0,
          viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 18,
          },
          format: "0.0",
          textStyle: { color: "black" },
          titleTextStyle: { color: "black" },
          position: "left",
        },
        1: {
          title: `${this.filtersColorsData[1].label} %`,
          minValue: 40.0,
          maxValue: 100.0,
          viewWindow: {
            min: 40,
            max: 100,
          },
          format: "0.0",
          textStyle: { color: "blue" },
          titleTextStyle: { color: "blue" },
          position: "left",
        },
        2: {
          title: `${this.filtersColorsData[0].label} C`,
          minValue: 4.0,
          maxValue: 26.0,
          viewWindow: {
            min: 4,
            max: 26,
          },
          format: "0.0",
          textStyle: { color: "red" },
          titleTextStyle: { color: "red" },
          position: "left",
        },
      },
      hAxis: {
        reverseCategories: true,
      },
    },
  };

My html:
<google-chart
        *ngIf="showLineChart"
        [data]="indexesColumnChart2"
      ></google-chart>

Result:

I tried with position: "left", direction: -1, side: "left", orientation: "vertical" and
hAxis: {
    reverseCategories: true
  }
```,



Thank you!

